# Whitelist Java-Functions in XSLT-Processing?

Tags: java, security, xslt, javax.xml

I use `javax.xml.transform.Transformer` to process some XML-data with a custom developed XSLT document. In this xslt-document, I call a function from my packages. To do this, I need to set the secure-processing-feature for the processor to false, because the secure mode does not allow calling Java functions:

```
final TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
factory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, false);
```

Now I wonder, if this is secure. Is it possible to create a whitelist that lists the allowed functions to be called during the processing? Is it even necessary, as I define the stylesheet on my own and no user input can be added here?

Comment: XSLT is awful, have you considered using [freemarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/) instead?

Comment: Even though you might be right, this does not help too much. Lets just assume XSLT must be used.

Comment: Sure... so long as you've considered it. I feel for you, XLST is awful... best of luck!

Comment: Depending on your needs and the setup options you have, you could consider to move to Saxon HE (current supported versions are 11 and 12) and there you can implement your own set of needed, integrated extension functions to call Java while direct, reflexive calls into Java are not supported. I am not aware of such a feature for the JRE built-in XSLT 1 Transformer.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but, unfortunately, XSLT is demanded.

Comment: Saxon is an XSLT (3) processor.

Comment: Whoops, youre right - I meant Javas standard xslt processor from the xml packages.

Answer (score 0):

The primary purpose of "secure processing mode" is to make it reasonably safe for your application to execute untrusted XSLT/XPath code. If you trust the XSLT code you are executing, then in principle there is no need to set "secure processing mode" on. Unfortunately you may run foul of the security police in your organisation, who will often mandate that all such controls be set to their most secure setting possible, without actually looking at the detail of what this means.

The question "is this secure?" is meaningless without analysis of what risks you are trying to protect against.

As Martin Honnen mentions, you could switch to Saxon, which allows you to register specific Java classes/methods as extension functions in such a way that these are the only external calls allowed.